# change the cpp version used by clang in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang

I am using vscode with the clang extension as my IDE for c/c++, and In my latest program I tried to use `std::optional` but got a red line under it.

Now the problem is that clang is trying to compile my code as gnu++14 (the default) and `std::optional` is available from gnu++17.

In my cmake file I can use the flag -std=gnu++17 so the code will compile correctly but I don't know how to change it in the vscode extension.

EDIT: i am using arch Linux

Comment: just use the cmake extension and let it configure vscode for you. P.S [CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) is the proper way to set the cmake c++ standard

Comment: I get that people like vscode because of its minimalism, but when I see questions like this (and I see a lot) I can’t help but wonder why people don’t try a more fully featured ide like clion, which has a handy little drop down menu to set the std version built in.

Comment: If you are on macOS the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac) shows you the modifications needed for tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json with that said since you mentioned CMake VSCode does support CMake via the CMakeTools extension. Are you using that?

Comment: setting up the CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD diden't work, i think that its because the problem is in the clang extension and not in vscode